Lorentz invariance in statistical physics
Given a function $f=f(p^\mu)$ with $p^\mu$ the four-momentum I can integrate it over the full phase-space with $\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}p\ f(p^\mu)$. This, however, is usually not very useful, since the four components of $p^\mu$ are not independent and must obey the mass-shell condition $p^2=p^\mu p_\mu = -m^2$.
For this reason when we integrate on the momentum space we constraint ourselves to the mass shell by including a Dirac delta $\delta(p^2+m^2)$ which leads to the standard Lorentz invariant measure
$$
\int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}p\ \delta(p^2+m^2)f(p^\mu)=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^dp}{2p_0}f(p^\mu)
$$
where $p_0$ solves the mass shell condition and now all the $p_0$ in $f$ are to be understood as functions of $\vec{p}$.
My question is: Why isn't the Lorentz invariant measure necessary in statistical physics? See e.g., here. Is it because the thermal bath ruins the Lorentz symmetry anyway?
But then, why do we use the Lorentz invariant measure when we compute thermodynamic quantities using relativistic kinetic theory?
Does this depend on the choice of the Hamiltonian, e.g. $H_1=p_0$ vs $H_2=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}p_\mu p_\nu$?
